# For a 1-parameter family of metrics, how do we compute the derivative of the intrinsic geometrical objects like curvature, Hessian, etc

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

Consider a family of metrics and functions $(g(t), u(t))$ on $M:= \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B_1$ satisfying
$$ g(0) = g_0, \quad g'(0) = \tilde g, \quad u(0) = u_0, \quad u'(0) = \tilde u$$
where $g_0$, $\tilde g$ are fixed metrics on $M$ and $u_0$, $\tilde u$ are fixed functions on $M$.

Is there an easy way to compute things like:

$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \Delta_{g(t)}u(t)$$
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} A_{g(t)}$$
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} tr_{g(t)} A$$
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\nu_{g(t)} \cdot \nabla_{g(t)}u(t)$$
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} Hess_{g(t)} u(t) $$
where $A_{g(t)}$ is the second fundamental form on the sphere $S_r$ of radius $r$, and $\nu_{g(t)}$ is the normal unit outward vector field on $S_r$ with respect to $g(t)$.

I am having a very hard time doing this. It's getting very messy and I am not trusting my computations. Is there a book or reference that does things like that?

Any help or reference is appreciated.

(You can suppose that $g_0$ takes the from $dr^2 + h(r)^2 \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the round metric on $S^2$ and $h$ is some positive function. )

Comment: if I remember correctly (though I could be wrong), you may be able to find these formulas perhaps in Besse's "Einstein manifolds". If not, then you would probably find them in a textbook on the Ricci flow.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at Besse and some books on Ricci flow. I couldn't find the variation of the second fundamental form and $\Delta_{g(t)}u(t)$.

Comment: ok, sorry about that. I have a small remark, that $\tilde{g}$ need not be positive-definite in general.

Comment: The calculations for the Ricci and mean curvature flows provide good guides on how to do the calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped: https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf.

Comment: I did the calculations for some of them myself. I am not too confident they are correct. I can share them if anyone is interested. For $\Delta_{g(t)}u(t)$, I really didn't find a nice form for it, and also didn't find it in Ricci and mean curvature flow books.

Comment: Topping's lecture notes on Ricci flow are useful for this sort of thing (I dont think they have all the calculations you want though).

Comment: Yes they are useful. Check section 2.3: Deformation of geometric quantities as the metric is deformed. http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf